# Automatically deducing element type of pair container from the function template argument

Tags: c++, templates, std-pair

I want to write a template function which takes a container of key-value pairs (e.g `map<K,V>` or `vector<pair<K,V>>`) and returns a container of container of keys. For example:

```
template<typename C, typename K, typename V>
vector<vector<K>> partition_keys(const C& input)
{
    vector<vector<K>> result;
    ...
    // do something
    for (const auto &pair : input)
    {
        cout << pair.first << "," << pair.second << std::endl;
    }
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Here's how I would like to call it:

```
// map
map<string, string> product_categories;
partition_keys(product_categories); // doesn't work
partition_keys<map<string, string>, string, string>(product_categories); // have to do this
// vector
vector<pair<string, string>> movie_genres;
partition_keys(movie_genres); // doesn't work
partition_keys<vector<pair<string, string>>, string, string>(movie_genres); // have to do this
```

But, the compiler cannot deduce the template parameters K and V without explicitly specifying them. I want the function to work with any container having pair of any type; so I want to avoid writing separate template functions for `map<K,V>`, `list<pair<K,V>>`, `vector<pair<K,V>>`, etc.

So, I had to modify the template function signature as follows to make it work the way I want:

```
template<typename C, 
         typename K = remove_const_t<C::value_type::first_type>, 
         typename V = C::value_type::second_type>
vector<vector<K>> partition_keys(const C& input);
```

Is there a better way to do this? Is it a good practice to deduce types of `K` and `V` based on `value_type` of `C`? Also, there is a possibility of caller explicitly passing invalid arguments for `K` and `V`.

Note also how I had remove constness of key type by calling `remove_const_t` because for a `map`, `C::value_type::first_type` is a `const` type and the standard doesn't allow creating a collection of a `const` type.

Comment: This sounds like an xy-problem, why would you want to get a collection of keys? Why not get the range of keys?

Comment: Why a container of container of keys and not just a container of keys?

Comment: @ChristianHackl, because I want to partition the keys in to groups based on some condition. However, the exact type - container or container of container - doesn't matter for the problem posed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the right way, more specifically:

```
template<typename C,
         typename Pair = typename C::value_type,
         typename Key = std::remove_const_t<typename Pair::first_type>,
         typename Value = typename Pair::first_type
        >
vector<vector<Key>> partition_keys(const C& input)
```

is correct [(Demo)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4d1d1d4cdea9d01). However, if you need to use similar type decomposition for different template functions like:

```
....repeat above templated type decomposition....
vector<vector<Key>> sorted_keys(const C& input);

....repeat above templated type decomposition....
vector<vector<Key>> filtered_keys(const C& input);
```

It may be too much of typing to do. In that case, you can make a simple trait class to help you with that.

```
template<typename T>
struct PTraits{
    using pair_type  = typename T::value_type;
    using key_type   = std::remove_const_t<typename pair_type::first_type>;
    using value_type = typename pair_type::second_type;
};

template<typename T>
using KeyTypper = typename PTraits<T>::key_type;
```

Then use as...

```
template<typename C, typename Key = KeyTypper<C>>
vector<vector<Key>> partition_keys(const C& input);

template<typename C, typename Key = KeyTypper<C>>
vector<vector<Key>> sorted_keys(const C& input);

template<typename C, typename Key = KeyTypper<C>>
vector<vector<Key>> filtered_keys(const C& input);
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2e80c965508df2e)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think your answer and the other answer using `auto` in the return type can be combined effectively like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ee36cddd28462f4). This would address my concern about the caller overriding the Key parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine. If you don't like the clutter in template parameters, you can put the key type directly in the return type, possibly in trailing form:

```
template <typename C>
auto partition_keys(const C& input)
    -> vector<vector<remove_const_t<typename C::value_type::first_type>>>;
```

or rely on return type deduction for normal functions and omit the return type entirely:

```
template <typename C>
auto partition_keys(const C& input)
{
    vector<vector<remove_const_t<typename C::value_type::first_type>>> result;
    //...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Err, both of them [fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f3de1919f994923). Curious about the first case, even if we get the template function declaration correctly, how should he declare an object of the return type in the body.... I mean, how does he declare `result` and populate it as would be possible in your second code? [This is what](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49b5f26fed7af371) I mean.

Comment: @WhiZTiM This [compiles successfully](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4ab9c9c0a7500d2).

Comment: @rabindra. Yep.. right. :-). And the question I posed for the case of specifying the return type of `auto`? ...just curious though...

Comment: @WhiZTiM, I guess the line from the second case would have to be used in the first case also to declare the type of `result`. So, I think the second case seems to be better.

Comment: @WhiZTiM, it didn't compile because I missed one closing `>`. Fixed.

Comment: @WhiZTiM and yes, as rabindra says, you'l have to paste the same type instead of `XXXXX` or possibly do `decltype(partition_keys(input)) result;` like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07ffdf67a670fd9b).